# app crashed sendSynchronousRequest in ios

Tags: ios

I dont know why my **app crashes** in this line

```
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

This is my code:

```
NSString * urlString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:MAINURL];

NSHTTPURLResponse * response;
NSError * error;
NSMutableURLRequest *request;

request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                   timeoutInterval:120];

if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"callWebServiceFor"] isEqualToString:nil]) {
    // [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    NSString * strSessionId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"sessionId"];
    if(strSessionId != nil)
        [request setValue:strSessionId forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
}
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
// Storing session headers when user logs in successfully
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"callWebServiceFor"] isEqualToString:@"login"]) {
    NSArray * all = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]; //testing
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies:all forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] mainDocumentURL:nil];
    NSString * strSessionId;
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in all) {
        strSessionId = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:cookie.value];
        //  NSLog(@"Session value: %@",cookie.key];
        //  NSLog(@"Session value: %@",strSessionId);
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:strSessionId forKey:@"sessionId"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"callWebServiceFor"];
}
if (data != nil) {
    dispatch_async(kBackGroudQueue, ^{
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleWebServiceResponse:)
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
} else {
    [SwapweekUtilViewController showAlert:@"Internet" :@"Check your Internet Connection"];
}
```

Comment: Even it does not throw any error exceptions

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see why your code is crashing in `NSURLConnection  sendSynchronousRequest:`, and you've yet to post a stacktrace to verify that fact, however this code might crash (if `strSessionId` is `nil`):

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:strSessionId forKey:@"sessionId"];
```

and this code **will** crash:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"callWebServiceFor"];
```

(Use `removeObjectForKey:` to remove an object from User Defaults.)

Also this is very poor:

```
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"callWebServiceFor"] isEqualToString:nil]) {
```

(Test for `[NSString length] == 0` instead.)

This is poor too:

```
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in all) {
    strSessionId = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:cookie.value];
    //  NSLog(@"Session value: %@",cookie.key];
    //  NSLog(@"Session value: %@",strSessionId);
}
```

(`break` once you have a non-empty `strSessionId` and just do `strSessionId = cookie.key;` instead of that `initWithString`).